# Automating VS2022 project template export as a part of the Azure DevOps build pipeline

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-2022

We have a series of Visual Studio 2022 projects that we export into Visual Studio project templates. Write now, it's entirely a manual process.

I want to make that exporting process a part of Azure DevOps but I have no idea how to go about it.

Ideally, it would look something like this:

1. Commit changes to the project in Vidual Studio
2. Azure DevOps builds project
3. Azure DevOps exports the project as a Project Template
4. Azure DevOps copies the zip file output to Artifacts

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What steps have *you* taken to figure out "how to go about it"? You know what you want to do and the rough steps involved in doing so.

Comment: @DanielMann I don't understand what you're asking. Yes, I know how to do the export manually through Visual Studio (Project -> Export template....). Making the ADO pipeline  drive that process is where I'm at a complete loss. Sadly, my Google searches have not been fruitful.